# Turn group of points into single pixel

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a b&w image with 4 groups of points, and I need to transform each group into a single point.

My idea was to find remove points by distance, so if a pixel is maybe 20px away from the other, I would turn remove one and keep the other, and repeat the process until I only got 4 pixels, but it doesn't seem really good for performance.

Is there a better way I can do it?

Thanks

Image:

[image]

Comment: You could use findContours or connectedComponentsAnalysis

Comment: Please share your actual image, rather than a plot of it with labelled axes and a grid all over it!

Comment: @MarkSetchell i've edited it with the right image! it was actually that matplotlib stuff that are drawn when you plot it on jupyter

Comment: Follow @Micka 's excellent advice above.

Comment: Groups of touching pixels are called connected components. The function findContours will return the outlines of all connected components as lists of points. You can pick one of them. If you want a more "central" point, you can compute the centroid, but is some cases it can lie outside the outline !

Comment: why is everyone taking this literally and _erasing_ parts of the image? just find the components, calculate centroids (good enough here), and _having the coordinates_ is likely enough. if it REALLY needs to be drawn, draw the points in a new image.

Comment: @Micka and Yves. thanks, that was really useful! I'll try it

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz i think that the erasing would be to don't reescan pixels you've already scanned. But the connected components seems to avoid this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is not so far from a workable solution. You can craft a simple algorithm that works as follows:

- scan the image in raster order until you meet a white pixel,
- from this pixel, erase the whole connected component by seed-filling,
- restore the initial pixel and continue the scan to the end of the image.

To erase,

- set the current pixel to black,
- recurse on all white neighbors (you can consider the four pixels with a common edge and optionally the four ones touching by a corner).

Beware that if the connected components components are large, a stack overflow can occur. Also mind the edge pixels of the image (some neighbors are missing).

This algorithm is pretty efficient, as it will visit the black pixels only once, and the white pixels just twice (once when white, then a second time after erasing).

Comment: I did this scanning each pixel by a radius and removing the white pixels, and repeating 4 times. But there seems to be a better solution if you're using openCV that is based on graph teory, I will also try it. Thanks

Comment: @EnzoDtz: this is not what I describe.

Comment: I might have described it badly, but I totally got what you said. As I mentioned on @stateMachine comments, I think that your solution would fit better to the question topic if someone got here by searching, so I will mark it as the solution. Maybe it would be nice to provide some code, even if i didn't asked in the post. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible solution. Basically, I detect the four blobs on your original image, get their *bounding boxes* and compute their *centroids*. I use the centroids to `flood-fill` at this position with black color, and then just draw a pixel in the same position.

However, your image is gigantic and compressed. I resized it (if you don't want to resize it, you can keep the `scalePercent` at `100`), convert it to `grayscale` and then `threshold` it - as I said, your image is compressed and some pixels aren't really white, so thresholding gives me a true binary image:

```
# imports:
import cv2

# Set image path
imagePath = "C://opencvImages//"
imageName = "juPHJ.jpg"

# Read image:
inputImage = cv2.imread(imagePath + imageName)

# Resize percent:
scalePercent = 20

# Calculate new dimensions:
newWidth = int(inputImage.shape[1] * scalePercent / 100)
newHeight = int(inputImage.shape[0] * scalePercent / 100)

# Resize image
inputImage = cv2.resize(inputImage, (newWidth, newHeight))

# Input deep copy
inputCopy = inputImage.copy()

# Convert BGR to grayscale:
grayInput = cv2.cvtColor(inputImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Get binary image via Otsu:
_, binaryImage = cv2.threshold(grayInput, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

Now, let's extract the white blobs, get their bounding boxes, compute the centroids and `flood-fill` accordingly:

```
# Extract blobs:
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(binaryImage, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Loop through the blobs, get their bounding boxes:
for i, c in enumerate(contours):

    # Get blob bounding box:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    # Compute centroid:
    cx = int(x + 0.5 * w)
    cy = int(y + 0.5 * h)

    # Flood-fill at the center:
    fillPosition = (cx, cy)
    fillColor = (0, 0, 0)
    cv2.floodFill(binaryImage, None, fillPosition, fillColor, loDiff=(10, 10, 10), upDiff=(10, 10, 10))

    # Draw a pixel at the center:
    binaryImage[cy, cx] = 255

    # Show new Image:
    cv2.imshow("New Image", binaryImage)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This is the output (you have to really zoom-in to see the single pixels, though):

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That solution is really cool. I also find the function `connectedComponentsWithStats` from openCV that returns the centroids.

Comment: Turns out that the `findCountours` solutions seems to be better, since with the `connectedComponents`, it will not remove the other isolated points that weren't visible in the original image. This was deffinetly what fitted the best in my scenario, altought the other provided solutions were more related to anyone that might search for this. Thanks a lot!